# How to split a string between all chars and int in Python

Tags: python, string, string-parsing

For example I want to convert "2pL11H10K" into [2, p, L, 11, H, 10, K]

Comment: You will probably need an if statement and regular expressions ... Have you tried any code so far and, if so, can you post it and the errors you received?

Comment: I have not tried any code yet

Comment: What if two or more letters are adjacent? Should they be separate or together in the result?

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression.
Example

```
your_string = "2pL11H10K"
items = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]|\d+', your_string)
print(items)
```

then you got

```
['2', 'p', 'L', '11', 'H', '10', 'K']
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are necessary and there have already been some quality answers given, but you will also need to convert the numbers from `str()` to `int()`. This can also be achieved using regular expressions, for example with `[0-9]+` to identify one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the logic for this in a `loop` checking the if the previous element is a digit or char if you do not wish to import any modules. However `regex` would likely be the most elegant solution.

```
result = []
for e in string:
    if result:
        if result[-1].isdigit() and e.isdigit():
            result[-1] = result[-1] + e
        else:
            result.append(e)
    else:
        result.append(e)
```